# Hide all output from a background process

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I have a bunch of commands in my `zshrc` which invoke another command in the background. The background command is an alias to a text-to-speech program (I use it to give me audio cues when processes like test suites and patches finish).

It currently gets invoked like this:

```
alert "Message for this current task" &
```

Pretty simple.

However, when I use this format, I get this output:

```
$ alert "Foobar" &
[1] 85072
$
[1]  + done       alert "Foobar"
$
```

I want to suppress the output of the pid and the `done` message. How do I do that?

I tried `alert "Foobar" > /dev/null &` but that only pipes the output of alert to devnull.

I tried `alert "Foobar" & > /dev/null` but that did unexpected bad things that I don't fully understand.

How do I use `&` in 'quiet' mode?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a subshell to get rid of the job control messages:

```
$ alias alertme="xmessage Alert!"
$ ( alertme & )
$
```

If your commad also produces some output to STDOUT and/or STDERR, pipe those to `/dev/null`:

```
$ ( alertme > /dev/null 2>&1 & )
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but I thought I needed to leave the & outside the (), so naturally it still gave me the output.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly neater version of another answer here:

```
(&>/dev/null alertme &)
```

Comment: What's the difference between `(&>/dev/null cmd &)` and `(cmd &>/dev/null &)`?